# What's with 'ld'?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, ld

I'm a newbie in assembly, and am having trouble creating executable file in linux,
I had this assembly code saved it as file.asm and compiled it using terminal:

```
nasm -f elf file.asm
ld -o file file.o"        // the problem lies here. I always get this notice:
ld: i386 architecture of input file 'file.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64"
```

so, I cannot proceed to running the file. Is this maybe because of my version of ubuntu, though, I think not. :( I don't know. Help.

Comment: `-f elf` is shorthand for `-f elf32`. Try using `-f elf64` instead. Or if you really wanted to build a 32-bit application you could use something like this for linking: `gcc -m32 -o test test.o`

Comment: Right. Or if just using `ld`, `ld -o file file.o -melf_i386`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your system architecture. I think you are using 64 bit CPU and 64 bit operating system. To solve this issue, try replace elf with elf64. For more information, run the command: 
**nasm -hf**